# Parse.com Cloud code needs error "success/error was not called" to work

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have this bit of cloudcode, but it only seems to work when i get the "success/error was not called" error as a response.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Move", function(request, response) {
    var params = request.params;
    var Player = Parse.Object.extend("Player");

    query = new Parse.Query("Player");
    query.get(params.id, {
        success: function(p) {
            switch(params.direction){
                case "up":    p.set("mapy", p.get("mapy") - 1, { success: function(p) {}, error: function(p, error) { response.error(error);}}); break;
                case "down":  p.set("mapy", p.get("mapy") + 1, { success: function(p) {}, error: function(p, error) { response.error(error);}}); break;
                case "left":  p.set("mapx", p.get("mapx") - 1, { success: function(p) {}, error: function(p, error) { response.error(error);}}); break;
                case "right": p.set("mapx", p.get("mapx") + 1, { success: function(p) {}, error: function(p, error) { response.error(error);}}); break;
            }
            p.save();
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
        }
    });
}
//response.success("success ");
```

If this last line is ran (not commented) I will get a positive response BUT no alteration to the variables on parse
Should i be using aftersave? if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are working on the returned object, so I think you should use the concept of Promise Chaining here: https://parse.com/docs/js/guide#promises

```
Parse.Cloud.define("Move", function(request, response) {
    var params = request.params;
    var Player = Parse.Object.extend("Player");

    query = new Parse.Query("Player");
    query.get(params.id).then(function(p) {
            switch(params.direction){
                case "up":    p.set("mapy", p.get("mapy") - 1); break;
                case "down":  p.set("mapy", p.get("mapy") + 1); break;
                case "left":  p.set("mapx", p.get("mapx") - 1); break;
                case "right": p.set("mapx", p.get("mapx") + 1); break;
            }
            return p.save();
        }).then(function(success){
                response.success();
        },function(error){
           console.error("Got an error " + error.code + " : " + error.message);
           });
    });
```